# Count the number of rows with xpath but .size() is not available

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to count the number of rows in table and based on my research for webdriver, I should be using as code below. However, I am unable to see .size() method populated and i'll be appreciated if someone can explain to me?

```
int rowCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hitlist']/form/table/tbody/t")).size();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.findElement` will only find one element, the return type is `WebElement`.

You want `driver.findElements`, which has return type of `List<WebElement>`. ([Source here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java#147))

Use it like this:

```
int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='hitlist']/form/table/tbody/tr")).size();
```

Comment: @user2388556: Noticed the difference between `findElement` and `findElements`? Did you read what I wrote?